# Is there a way to save the email as a file while using MailKit c#?

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

I would like to save the entire email to the disk with all the headers instead to relay to an SMTP server using MimeKit, is this possible?.

I am aware that the Message itself can be written into a file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. You can do:

```
message.WriteTo (fileName);
```